# attached volumes do not appear in /dev

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have a server at amazon ec2.

I used the following AMI to install Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit: `ami-1aad5273`
it uses ebs root device type.

I use elastifox plugin installed on firefox 7. 
when I go to 'Volumes and snapshots' tab and attach a volume to the instance I created, after the status is changed to 'attached' i don't see the device in the server's /dev directory.

how can I check or debug why it's not mounted?

thanks

---

it seems that ebs volumes appear as /dev/xvd? instead of /dev/sd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the recent Ubuntu releases, you will see the attached volumes show up under names like /dev/xvdh where they used to be at /dev/sdh.

However, when you specify the device named with the Amazon command like tools, API calls, EC2 console, and other places external to the instance, you still need to use the old /dev/sdh form.